# Renderizar componentes de acordo com a rota

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com React. Tenho o arquivo index.jsx abaixo:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { store } from './_helpers';
import { App } from './App';


render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Que renderiza o componente App para a div com id app, que está no index.html. Ok, também tenho nessa aplicação um componente de login que é renderizado através de rotas, funciona perfeitamente, entretanto, depois de logado, o usuário entra no componente Home, aonde existe um menu que eu gostaria que quando um item for clickado, ele renderize este outro componente dentro de uma div no componente home. Como posso fazer isso? Creio que não seja com state, porque isso invalidaria as rotas, ou estou enganado?

Edit 1 = Mostrando o app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { history } from '../_helpers';
import { alertActions } from '../_actions';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../_components';
import { HomePage } from '../HomePage';
import { Timesheet } from "../Timesheet";
import { LoginPage } from '../LoginPage';
import { RegisterPage } from '../RegisterPage';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        history.listen((location, action) => {
            // clear alert on location change
            dispatch(alertActions.clear());
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (

                <Router history={history}>
                    <div>
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/timesheet" component={Timesheet} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return {
        alert
    };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export { connectedApp as App };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar `ReactDOM.render()` não apenas para renderizar o elemento Root, mas para toda inserção de componentes, exceto se voce estiver usando Server Side Rendering.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const PrivateComponent = (props) => {
    return(
        <h1>Eba, usuario logado clicou lá.</h1>
    );
}

class Menu extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        let logged = this.props.user.logged;
        if (!logged) {
            //se nao estiver logado, nada é renderizado;
            return;
        }

        ReactDom.render(<PrivateComponent/>, document.querySelector(".target"));
    }
    render()
    {
        return (
            <nav>
                //lá vai verificar se está logado ou nao
                <span onClick={this.handleClick}></span>

                //se estiver logado vai cair aqui o seu component
                <div className{"target"}></div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

class Home extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <header>Nosso website</header>

            <Menu user={{logged: true}} />

            <main>Nosso artigo fantástico</main>

            <footer>Créditos á....</footer>
        );
    }
}
```